# File Upload Firebase Storage Error in React Js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I'm new to React. I've created an Image uploader using FileUploader and Firebase. While I'm uploading an image, there is occurring an error.

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'player/c6f82c8d-9045-47f4-88b1-4574901411a7.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)

[image]
Need Help to Resolve this issue.

Comment: This means the user doesn't have permission to write the data. I recommend searching for the error message as this has been covered befiore: https://www.google.com/search?q=storage%2Funauthorized

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer from one expert. Changed the false to true of read, write rules in my firebase User account.
[image]